# Find average after annotation subtract without aggregate Django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a lot of queries that want to return in a single request, I have a query with an aggregate and when we concat the queryset with this function and try to serialize the function returns an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
 line 35, in inner
     response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line
 128, in _get_response
     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line
 126, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line
 54, in wrapped_view
     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 103,
 in view
     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 483, in
 dispatch
     response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 443, in
 handle_exception
     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in
 dispatch
     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\drf_multiple_model\mixins.py", line
 106, in list
     self.check_query_data(query_data)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\drf_multiple_model\mixins.py", line 40,
 in check_query_data
     '`{}` key'.format(self.__class__.__name__, key) django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['All items in the
 ConversasAPIViewSet querylist attribute should contain a `queryset`
 key']
```

Is there any kind of solution for this problem?

APIViewSet:

```
class ConversasAPIViewSet(ObjectMultipleModelAPIViewSet):  
    kpiDTO = KpiDTO(6)
    json = Conversas.objects.values('nome'
                                   ).annotate(deltaTime = (Max('data') - Min('data'))
                                ).aggregate(tempoMedioTotal=Avg('deltaTime'))

    qtdUsuariosMes, qtdMensagensMes, fraseIntentEntity, tempoMedioTotal = kpiDTO.retornaDTO()
    querylist = [
        {'queryset': qtdMensagensMes, 'serializer_class': QuantidadeMensagensMesSerializer, 'label': 'qtdMensagensMes'},
        {'queryset': qtdUsuariosMes, 'serializer_class': QuantidadeUsuariosMesSerializer,'label': 'qtdUsuariosMes' },
        {'queryset': fraseIntentEntity, 'serializer_class': EntidadeIntencaoSerializer, 'label': 'fraseIntentEntity'},
        {'queryset': json , 'serializer_class': TempoMedioSerializer,  'label': 'tempoMedio'}
    ]
```

Serializer:

```
class TempoMedioSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    tempoMedioTotal = serializers.CharField()
```

Comment: Add the full traceback, please.

Comment: It's done dude!

Comment: You can consider posting the solution for it.

Comment: I added the traceback as you said, i don't solved the problem

Comment: I noticed `json` is using `aggregate`, which returns a dictionary, not a QuerySet. I'm unsure of how your data is structured, could you describe exactly what you're trying to get out of the Conversas queryset? There may be another way to go about getting what you need out of it.

Comment: I'm trying to get the average time of user stay in conversation, beacuse this i do the subtract of Max(date) and Min(date) first, and then i want to get the Avg of this substract

Comment: Django aggregates usually return a dictionary not a queryset. Besides, you should be doing that in the `get_queryset()` method. And why do you have so many querysets for a single view? it's difficult to understand where the issue is

Comment: I need to return a lot of information (that needs a lot of queries) to do only one view , because that i dont want to do 5,6, 10 requests (that loses performance), for just construct one view.